# What is Adi Shesha's role during Kalki avatar?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, adisesha, kalki

In Ramavatar, Adisesha took the avatar of Lakshmana. In Krishnavatar, he incarnated as Balarama. After that, Adisesha took the avatar of Ramanujacharya to spread the Vaishnavism. It is also believed that Raghavendra is Adisesha's avatar. Likewise, is there any puranic reference for Adishesha's avatar at end of Kaliyuga to accompany Narayana as Kalki who will come on a white horse with sword?

Comment: The whole Kalki Puran seems interpolation as he is killing Buddhists in Kalki Puran. Seems it has been written when India was becoming Buddhist nation.

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore, idk about kalki purana, but avatara of kalki is definitely not interpolation..

Comment: Yes @ram Avatar isn't interpolation, only Puran is.

Comment: @Aghori You can't say Kalki Purana is interpolation as it says it Kalki kills Buddhists. Who knows what happens tomorrow? What if India becomes Hindu Rastra or something like that or at least Buddhism become  more popular in west and whole Dharma worsens with Buddhism? Also, Lord Vishnu deluded them as Buddha and it's his responsibility to give His devotees Moksha by killing them.

Comment: If you're talking about Sri Raghavendra Swami, they're believed to be an avatar of Sankukarna, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22281/whose-avatar-was-sri-raghavendra-swami/23963#23963) and not Adi Shesha.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki

In this you will find:-
 it is written in Kalki Purana that he will have four brothers who are Sumanta, Prajna and Kavi.

Comment: But who among them will be adi sesha's incarnation? And what will be his role?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Who among them will be  Sesha's incarnation?