# Whose avatar was Sri RAghavendra Swami?

Tags: avatars, dvaita

Famous in the madhwa line, Sri Raghavendra is linked with many miracles. His samaadhi is at mantrAlayam.

Whose avatAr was he ?

Comment: just wondering why do you use capital 'A' in between words?

Comment: Its the way of transcribing for devanagari script. Exanple vaanee can be written as vAnI maataa can be written as mAtA etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to start by pointing out that it's not his samadhi but the vrindavana which is present in Mantralaya.

Sri Raghavendra Swami is considered to be the 4th incarnation of Sankukarna, who was an attendant of Lord Brahma. He was designated with the task of providing Lord Brahma with the articles needed for daily worship.

From the book, [Sri Raghavendra Teertha - Life history and works.](http://www.gururaghavendra1.org/raghavendra.pdf)

> It was a divine plan. One day Sankukarna was late in bringing the articles of worship to
>   Brahmadeva, who was not happy with the delay caused. A curse outwardly (a boon really) befell
>   SankuKarna to be born as a human being in the mundane world.

The four incarnations of Sankukarna were [Prahlada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prahlada), [Bahlika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahlika_(Mahabharata)), [Sri Vyasaraaja Theertha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyasatirtha) and Sri Raghavendra Swamiji.

A nice read on the life of Sri Raghavendra Swami is [Sri Raghavandra Mahatmyam - Saint of Mantralaya](https://archive.org/details/SHREERAGHAVENDRAMAHATMYAMSAINTOFMANTRALAYA), which also mentions this story at the very start:

> Shankukarnakya devasthu brahma shapasya boothale
>   Prahalada ithi vikhyatho bhoobaraksha pane rathara
>   [...] raghavendraksha yathi rupena sarvadha
>   kaliyuge ramaseva kurvan mantralaye bhaveth

One of the books which mention the story in detail is [Kaliyugada Kalpataru, by Raja Gururajacharya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23964/is-the-kaliyugada-kalpataru-available-online). There is an entire chapter dedicated to this story called "Shankukarna". If you know the Kannada language, [you can read it online.](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.382068/2015.382068.Kaliyuga-Kalpataru#page/n107/mode/2up)

Comment: What about incarnation of prahlada ?

Comment: I can understand the other three, but why would he incarnate as Bahlika?  Bahlika was the brother of Shantanu and he fought in the Kaurava side in the Mahabharata war, but that's about all that's notable about him.  I'm not sure what connection he has to Bhakti.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I did not get your comment. Do you want to ask about the incarnations of prahlada? If that's the case, then the 3 others whom I've mentioned can be considered as his incarnations.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I'm not that aware of the reasoning behind that particular incarnation. The biography doesn't speak much about it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan shantanu was not ordinary person he was a rajarishi with great powers his brother too would be a special man

Comment: @BhargavRao dude do you know what is a vrindavana ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, Picture me confused, I'm not sure what you want to convey by that statement. FWIW, it is the vrindavana which is present at Mantralaya. You can certainly ask anyone else who stays there, if you think that I'm wrong.

Comment: @BhargavRao vrindavana is samadhi only .. You can confirm from internet and your sources and revert back to.me

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Samadhi is the place where a guru is buried after they are dead. Vridavana is different. In this case, the ground is dug up and a small room like structure is created. The sage then enters the room, and then signals to others telling that they're ready to leave the world. After that, the room is covered up and a structure is placed atop that area. That *is* called a vridavana. So vrindavana is *not* a samadhi. (Vrindavana may be a specialized samadhi, but it certainly isn't a samadhi).

Comment: @BhargavRao so you mean dead body is not burried in vrindavana ?

Comment: No, it isn't buried there, because the sage who enters it will not be dead. (That's a reason why it's called Sajeeva Vrindavana). The building of a vridavana is explained in Kaliyugada Kalpataru, but unfortunately it is not present in English, else you could have read it. (BTW, in the present times, they no longer do that. If you check the vrindavana creation of the latest guru who was buried after they passed away, they are buried in a chamber underneath the vrindavana and then the vrindavana is built on top of it)

Comment: If I get the time and exact sources, I'll probably write a detailed answer to this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/how-sri-raghavendra-swamis-vrindabana-was-built, which would clarify your queries.

Comment: Interesting, I got a downvote on this post now. I'm not sure what I've missed, and have answered all the points asked by the OP in their question along with the right citations. I would like to know as to what I need to add so that I can improve the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, Also let me know if you need any more details, for my post to be a correct answer for your question. I will try to edit it to the best of my ability.

Comment: @BhargavRao do you know about kanchi paramacharya brindavan ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, I'm afraid, I don't know about them. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BhargavRao you say vrindavan is specialised samadhi but still its samadhi only right ? What difference it makes if its made before or after death ? It contains the dead body anyway.

Comment: Well @RakeshJoshi, if there is a specialized term for a particular thing, we *need* to use that.

Comment: And you start your answer with saying its not samadhi

Comment: Now we are just going in circles @RakeshJoshi, It is not a samadhi, it is a vrindavana. Do go through the comments which I've added again. I think I'll just stop here. It is of no use to continue the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Shankukarnakya devasthu brahma shapasya boothale
Prahalada ithi vikhyatho bhoobaraksha pane rathara
[...] raghavendraksha yathi rupena sarvadha
kaliyuge ramaseva kurvan mantralaye bhaveth

namaste sir can you please share complete sloka

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).